# Programmatically press button react native

Tags: react-native

I have a button that I was to programmatically click:

```js
<TouchableOpacity ref={ref}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the button I am using to trigger the button above:

```js
<SubscribeButton onPress={handleNext}>
              <SubscribeText>Subscribe</SubscribeText>
</SubscribeButton>
```

Here is my onPress function:

```js
const ref = useRef();

const handleNext = () => {
    ref.current.click();
  };
```

I keep getting the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ref.current.click')`

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you really need to programmatically press the button, or can you get away with simply calling the same function you to you to `onPress`? For example `<Button onPress={doSomething} />`, `const handleNext = () => { doSomething() }`

Comment: @samzmann I definitely need to programmatically press the button

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, because it does not animate the `TouchableOpacity` but it still does work.

`buttonRef.current._internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV.memoizedProps.onClick()`